# Error : Too many initializers for character array

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, char

Compile Errors :

prog.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:

prog.cpp:7:38: error: too many initializers for ‘char []’

```
 char even[] ={"E", "V", "E", "N" }; // this is a character array.
```

Hey, should i use const char* here even though i just included characters? I don't understand why this error is given.

Thanks for your time! Have a good day!

Comment: Voting to close as typo, `"E"` is a string literal, you mean `'E'`. Or simply `const char *even = "EVEN";` but you can't mix and match those.

Comment: "E" -> 'E', use single quote

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
char even[] ={'E', 'V', 'E', 'N'};
```

You are trying to initialise a char-array with strings.